# What creates /dev/stderr in FC14?

Tags: init, device, lxc, linux

I'm wondering what creates /dev/stderr on FC14.  rpm -qf doesn't show any package ownership.  I've dug through the init scripts and can't find it anywhere.

To provide some context, I'm creating a chroot'd jail to start with lxc.

Comment: On my (non RedHat) system, /dev/stderr is a symlink to /proc/self/fd/2.

Comment: But interestingly enough, it's not mentioned in /etc/udev/rules.d anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical creator of these files is "makedev". It does have a man page. Makedev, however, simply creates symlinks to /proc/self/fd/2 for /dev/stderr.

Comment: During the install process makedev is run, creating all the devices that you will (hopefully) ever need.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: udev

It's magical!

Comment: Is udev the correct answer for managing /dev entries inside a chroot?

Comment: @blueben answer is "maybe" but "probably not". Usually in a chroot you only want to give access to a very limited set of devices, otherwise the chroot could just open /dev/sda1 and go to town. udev may have a limited mode, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are entries for stdin, stdout and stderr in `/lib/udev/devices`. I don't think you should have to do anything special for them in a chrooted environment.

See also [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/76379/how-to-run-a-program-inside-chroot-with-stdin-stdout-available-to-caller). [Also interesting](http://www.mail-archive.com/misc@openbsd.org/msg17368.html).